# default assignment operator

Tags: c#, .net

Is there default assignment operator in c#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike C++, C# does not allow you to override the assignment operator.

For reference types, writing `x = y` will set `x` to refer to the same object (or `null`) that `y` does.

For value types, writing `x = y` will copy the fields in the `y` value to the `x` value.